# Facebook Embedded Post: callback events for like/share

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I have previously worked on a system that scraped content front facebook and presented it within a custom UI for sharing and liking. The only problem was that the app would need the 'publish_actions' permission and depending on the review process, they wouldn't always allow it.

I would love to work withing official facebook offerings - and the embedded posts looked like a winner. I would use the facebook 'like' button, but that is made to like *pages* not individual post urls.

However, when using the embedded posts - there seems to be no actions to subscribe to either FB.event.subscribe. I have searched high and low on facebook documentation but have not been able to get an answer.

Does anyone know of a way to listen to callbacks on the 'like/share/comment' actions on an embedded post?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not enabled because it would enable "like-gating", which is frowned upon.